# Conjugating the present simple with negation

Tags: negation, present-simple, conjugations

Suppose I am in a meeting now and I am a crew leader for a civil crew. My crew goes to the site at 6 am from the office, and they come to the room directly at 5 pm after finishing the job. They do not come to the office. In the meeting, which sentence should I use?

> Our crew  go to site at 6 am  and they not come office after finishing the job

or

> Our crew go to site at 6 o clock and they do not come Office after finishing the job

Comment: Neither sentence is anything much like English; but in modern English **all** negative finite verbs require an auxiliary, and if there is no other auxiliary present (such as a form of _be_ or _have_) you require a form of _do_.

Comment: @Colin Fine Wouldn't it be more helpful to give examples? I can hardly understand your explanation....[just saying]....

Comment: Meraj, for your information, the present simple in the negative is: do not + verb or does not+verb. So, /they do not come back to the office/.  Our crew goes. Third person.

Answer (score 1):

> Our crew **goes** to **the** site at 6 o clock and they do not come **to the** office after finishing the job

This would be the correct sentence. "Our crew" functions as a singular noun, so it needs "goes" not "go". You need the auxiliary "do" to negate come.  In modern English, for negating (and questions), you need either a modal verb or the dummy auxiliary verb "do" to make a grammatical sentence in all cases.

Comment: You're correct, but more emphasis on the queried difference (whether or not to use *do*, and why) would improve this answer.